# Which jQuery Function Should I Use: load() or ajax()?

Tags: jquery, ajax

At the moment I am using the ajax function like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'ajax_requests.php?action=get-list-of-all-users',
    data: '',
    success: function(output) {
        $('div.showHere').html(output);
    }
});
```

The PHP file `ajax_requests.php` has a switch statement which executes various commands based on the value it receives through the get parameter in the url.

So I'm not actually passing anything through the `data` parameter of the ajax function. I'm just telling the php script what I want done through the url.

Today it occurred to me that I could just well use the load() function. I can just do this to get the same result as above:

```
$('div.showHere').load('ajax_requests.php?action=get-list-of-all-users');
```

As long as I am using the `GET` method it seems like the much shorter code above is the better way to perform ajax requests. But I don't know much about jQuery or ajax to make the decision myself. So which should I use? and is load() better performance wise than using ajax() in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally, `load` pretty much does the exact process you were previously doing explicitly. Do whichever you prefer; if there is a performance difference, it's negligible.

The only place where performance would kick in is that, in your `load` example, you only search for `div.showHere` once. In the `ajax` example, that search is run every time that request completes. If this request will be fired often, this would be a small but significant performance difference.

However, that particular issue has to do with implementation of these methods rather than the methods themselves, and it can easily be resolved by caching the search's results:

```
var showHere = $('div.showHere');
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'ajax_requests.php?action=get-list-of-all-users',
    data: '',
    success: function(output) {
        showHere.html(output);
    }
});
```

Comment: so are you saying by putting the element to be searched for in a variable OUTSIDE the ajax request will result in it being cached and eliminate the performance issue that comes from jQuery searching the document for it every time?

Comment: @Tommy: yep :) A DOM search returns a special jQuery object that you can either interact with immediately, or store for later like any other value (string, integer, etc.). The really important bit is not that it's outside, exactly, but the fact that the query is run once and stored. Placing it outside the anonymous function, in the larger scope, is one easy way of doing that. This principle of storing queries you otherwise would run often is very important on jQuery-heavy pages.

Comment: @Tommy: oh! But an important caveat is that what you're storing is not the query but the results at the time the query is run. So, if you're likely to add or remove `div.showHere` elements between AJAX requests, then you *should* run the query every time to make sure you aren't *only* operating on the elements that existed when the page loaded. If the results will never change, however, (e.g. `#header`), then storing the results is definitely the way to go, and it doesn't only apply to AJAX results. If, say, a button click will affect all `div.showHere` elements, the same thing goes.

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't matter. The only caveat I would add is that if you plan on adding more functionality to it, then I would use the $.ajax, because you will need to anyway. The .load is doing the exact same thing.

As for performance, they will be nearly identical, but unless you have serious performance concerns, you shouldn't worry about it.